# Not able to install Jekyll because of therubyracer error on mac

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, therubyracer, libv8

I am trying to run `Jekyll` and I have the following contents in the `Gemfile`

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'jekyll-auth'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'jekyll-lunr-js-search'
gem 'rouge'
gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
```

I am running `bundle install` for installing the dependencies specified. Everything works fine until it tries to install a gem called `therubyracer`. Then the process is stopped by throwing the following error:

```
Installing nokogiri 1.11.3 (x86_64-darwin)
Fetching libv8 3.16.14.19
Installing libv8 3.16.14.19 with native extensions
Fetching ref 2.0.0
Installing ref 2.0.0
Fetching therubyracer 0.12.3
Installing therubyracer 0.12.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20210430-34242-1i9kf2u.rb extconf.rb --with-v8-dir\=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
checking for -lpthread... yes
checking for -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using
--with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version  (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with
the libv8 rubygem.

However, your system version of v8 could not be located.

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible
with 3.16.14.19 installed. You may need to use the
--with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds
before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll-lunr-js-search was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
    therubyracer
```

Now for fixing this error, I have tried the following commands as specified in some of the posts

```
brew install v8-315

gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.13' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8-315
```

But this is again giving the same error. I have tried

```
bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8
bundle config build.therubyracer --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8@3.15)
```

But there is no luck. I tried by specifying the brew based path for v8, in the command as follows:

`sudo gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir= /usr/local/Cellar/v8@3.15`

Even after doing all these, I am stuck with the same error which says `our system version of v8 could not be located.`

I am trying this on a Mac machine with `BigSur 11.2.3` is installed and the `Ruby` version is `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]` and `gem` is of version `3.0.3`.

It will be of great help if someone can tell me how this error can be fixed and I can install and run `Jekyll` successfully.

Comment: There is a space between `--with-v8-dir=` and `/usr/local/...` in your command. This may causes problems. Make sure there is no extra space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered same problem two years ago. I found that `libv8 3.16.14.19` is not compatible with `therubyracer 0.12.3` and wrote a [post](https://khiav223577.github.io/blog/2018/12/20/therubyracer-%E5%92%8C-libv8-%E7%9A%84%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%9D%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C/) to record my solution.

Try the following steps:

1. Clean up your system

```
gem uninstall -a libv8
gem uninstall -a therubyracer
```

2. Install `libv8` with specific version before installing `therubyracer`

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.15'
```

3. Install `therubyracer`

```
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'
```

4. Update `libv8` to the version specified in your gemfile

```
bundle
```

---

There may still have problem in macOS BigSur 11.2.

If it raises `fatal error: 'climits' file not found` in Step 2, try this:

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.15' -- --with-system-v8
```

If it raises errors in Step 3, try this:

```
brew install v8-315
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
```

Comment: When I try to install the libv8 version specified in step 2, I am getting an error that says `fatal error: 'climits' file not found`. Then I tried with `3.16.14.13`, but it is also showing error `clang: error: include path for libstdc++ headers not found`. I think there may be some problem with cpp here as it is showing `Using compiler: /usr/bin/g++ (clang version 4.2.1)`

Comment: @HappyCoder I managed to get a macbook with BigSur 11.2 and found a solution. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Still no luck. It is throwing another error: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.15/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version  (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with
the libv8 rubygem.

However, your system version of v8 could not be located`

Comment: In the path specified, I can see a symlink `v8@3.15 -> ../Cellar/v8@3.15/3.15.11.18_1`